# VS code unable to use SSH to push and pull from Bitbucket

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh, bitbucket

Currently, I'm using source tree to push & pull from Bitbucket with SSH.

However, when I try to use VS Code to do the same thing, it ask for a password.

And I get the following error after entering my Bitbucket password:

```
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/repo/repo.git/'
```

I searched for a few articles, but nothing I tried seemed to be working.

I'm on an M1 Macbook - OS Big sur.
This is for my professional Bitbucket account.

This was one of the docs I follow: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Comment: The repo's remote is using https://bitbucket.org. afaik this doesn't use an ssh connection?

Comment: evolutionxbox what do you mean by this?

Comment: I think it's using https not ssh

Comment: So you think the url is incorrect, or the set up is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and switch to the command-line, and go to the root folder of your local repository.

Check your remote URL with `git remote -v`: if it starts with `https://`, it won't use SSH. At all.

Switch to ssh: `git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:<me>/<MyRepo>` (`<me>` and `<myRepo>` are placeholder values for you to replace: don't use `<` and `>`)
Test also your SSH key was correctly [registered to your Bitbucket account](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/#Step-3.-Add-the-public-key-to-your-Account-settings): `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`.

Then switch back to VSCode, and see if your issue persists.

---

Jan. 2023: This is followed by [`microsoft/vscode` issue 170436](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170436).

Dec. 2023: that issue has been closed, since the issue does not seem to be present anymore.

Comment: No way. git cli works, git in vscode almost never works to me. Of course it's all ssh-based and your test command just worked.

Comment: @EnzoR So do you still have an issue? If yes, it is best to ask a separate question.

Comment: I will rather open a ticket. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @EnzoR Sure, let me know in a comment the reference of that ticket.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170436